# Etiquetas HTML en Json

Tags: html, json, jsonobject

mi pregunta es cómo hacer que las etiquetas html que vienen incluidas en un archivo json se ejecuten. En el JSON hay objeto que tiene saltos de linea, pero cuando lo ejecuto, estos saltos de linea aparecen con la etiqueta 
. Cómo puedo hacer que dichas etiquetas se ejecuten y haga el respectivo salto de linea? [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: `j=JSON.parse('{"html":"hola<br>que tal"}'); document.write(j.html)`

Answer (score 0):

Veo que estás usando React, es un dato importante que no mencionas directamente en la pregunta por ningún sitio. Para mostrar HTML "ejecutado" (mejor dicho interpretado o procesado) en React, hay que usar el atributo `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` en el código, pasándole un objeto con la propiedad `__html`. El siguiente código es un ejemplo:

```
function MyComponent() {
  const codigo = {
    __html: "<h1>¡Hola StackOverflow en Español!</h1>"
  };

  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={codigo} />;
}
```

Código basado en el de la [documentación de React](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml)